# Downloading RTools?

Tags: r, installation, path, warnings, rtools

Whenever I try to install packages it says I need to install RTools. I have installed it, and it is located on my desktop, in my documents, and in an R folder 4.1. Yet my computer is still saying it is not installed. I'm on a work computer.

I've tried to follow these steps https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html

write('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"', file = "~/.Renviron", append = TRUE) runs but seems to do nothing.
sys.which("make") just comes back with make ""

This is the error message when I try to install other packages:

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘\...Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/readxl_1.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1717257 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: "located on my desktop, in my documents, and in an R folder 4.1" None of these is a location where you should install Rtools to. Historically, installing it directly on C: has always worked best (see the example paths on top of the manual you linked to).